# Why does not Set implement PartialFunction?

Tags: scala

Programming in Scala: A Comprehensive Step-by-Step Guide, 2nd Edition, page 546:

> In the inheritance hierarchy below Iterable you find three traits: Seq,
>   Set, and Map. A common aspect of these three traits is that they all
>   implement the PartialFunction trait with its apply and isDefinedAt
>   methods.

However, this code does not compile (tried both 2.8.2 and 2.10.2):

```
Set(1, 2, 3).isDefinedAt(1)
```

With error:

```
value isDefinedAt is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
```

Is this a mistake in the book?

Comment: My guess is that `isDefinedAt` is a tester for whether element is present in collection or not, whereas `Set`'s `apply` or `contains` does that job instead. I mean, `Set`s are often (not always though) used almost solely for the purpose of testing for element presence.

Comment: And yes, that looks as obvious typo for me.

Comment: @cdshines - `isDefinedAt` is used to check if a partial function is defined for a given argument value. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction

Comment: @Lee, in context of collections that is the presence test, isn't that clear and obvious?

Comment: @cdshines - It's not a presence test, it returns whether the function is defined for some input value, not that it will return true. If you have something like `val f: PartialFunction[Int, Bool] = case { 1 => true }` then `f(2)` is not even defined. In this case `isDefinedAt(2)` returns false, while `f(2)` will throw an exception.

Comment: @Lee, oh, come on! Which of the words "in", "context", "of", "collections" didn't you see? `List(1,200,100).isDefinedAt(2)` is a test on the presence of the element on positional index `2`.

Comment: @cdshines - It has nothing to do with collections, which is the point I'm making. If `Set` were a partial function, then `isDefinedAt` would not be the same as `contains` or `apply`. As the accepted answer points out, `Set` is a total function, so `isDefinedAt` would always return true, which is obviously not the case for `contains`. `Set(1,200,100).isDefinedAt(2)` would return `true`, while `Set(1,200,100)(2)` would return `false`.

Comment: @cdshines, it sounds like you're not familiar with what partial functions are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure looks like it. Going as far as Scala 2.5.0:

- [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.0/scala/Seq.html) and [`Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.0/scala/collection/Map.html) extend `PartialFunction`:
- [`Set`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.5.0/scala/collection/Set.html) does not.

It seems sensible: `Set` maps from objects to `Boolean` values, so it's **always defined** (`true` for members, `false` for nonmbers).

Comment: Exactly, it is always defined, that's why `Set` extends `Function1[A, Boolean]` and not `PartialFunction[A, ???]`.

Comment: Note that `FunctionN` is *also* partial. There is no way to guarantee totality in Scala. The difference between `FunctionN` and `PartialFunction` is *not* that one is partial and the other isn't. The difference is that one knows about the concept of partiality and can be interrogated about it and the other doesn't. So, it's not nearly as obvious as you imply that `Set` couldn't implement `PartialFunction[T, Bool]` with `isDefinedAt(_: T) = true`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : I think I understand your statement in general (although I don't understand why you say "you can't guarantee totality in Scala" - care to elaborate?). However, here the point is more that extending `PartialFunction` caries some semantic weight *for the developer*: you see the header and might think "gee, applying this might work in some unusual way for some values". It would be entirely correct for every `Function` to extend `PartialFunction`, but I see no gain from such an approach, and the big disadvantage is noise.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato, all functions in Scala are partial, meaning that functions can fail to return a value for certain inputs (e.g. `def x(i: Int) = 1 / x` is partial because `x(0)` does not evaluate to a value; conversely, `def y(i: Int) = i + 1` is total because it has a value for any integer you can pass to it). A subclass of PartialFunction formalizes a function's partiality - it lets you test, via `isDefinedAt`, whether a function will terminate for a given input - as opposed to just calling it and letting it either return a value or diverge.

Comment: @Bill : true, and 'y' is also a partial function in addition to being total. That's why I mentioned *noise* in the API - you either make `PartialFunction` "optional", for total functions (or just those you don't want to introspect in that way), or you stick with the mathematical definition and make **every** function a `PartialFunction`. But then again: `isDefinedAt` is **also a function**. However, if anyone feels my answer is misleading in that aspect I'll gladly edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, a partial function `X => Y` is a function `X' → Y`, where X' is a subset of X. It would be incorrect to name Set a PartialFunction, because it is a total function - it is defined on every element.

That's why `Set(1, 2, 3).isDefinedAt _` doesn't make sense - it is always equals `true`

As was said before, Set[T] extends T => Boolean, an the apply method results in a true or false, whether element exists or not. If you want, you can create

```
trait NamedSet[T] extends Set[T] with PartialFunction[T,Boolean] {
   def isDefinedAt(x: T) = true
}
```

As you see, it doesnt't make sense