# Scala Multiple Inheritance: Differentiate between Iterable and PartialFunction in method arguments

Tags: scala, multiple-inheritance

I want to be able to define a method with the same name that has a different implementation if the argument is an `Iterable[T1]` vs a function: `T1 => T2`

However, many classes that implement `Iterable` also implement `PartialFunction`

For example:

```
object FunList {
  def foo(itr: Iterable[Int]) = println("hello")
  def foo(f: (Int => Int)) = println("Goodbye")
}

scala> FunList.foo(List(1))
<console>:9: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method foo in object FunList of type (f: Int => Int)Unit
and  method foo in object FunList of type (itr: Iterable[Int])Unit
match argument types (List[Int])
          FunList.foo(List(1))
```

currently my solution looks like this, but it does not match subclasses of `Iterable` which are not also subclasses of `PartialFunction`

```
case class SeqOrFun[T1, T2](f: (T1 => T2))
implicit def seqOrFun[T1, T2](f: (T1 => T2)) = SeqOrFun(f)

def unfurl[T1: Numeric, T2: Numeric](x: SeqOrFun[T1, T2], y: SeqOrFun[T1, T2]) = {
  (x.f, y.f) match {
    case (xs: Iterable[T1], ys: Iterable[T2]) => (xs, ys)
    case (xf: (T2 => T1), ys: Iterable[T2]) => (ys.map(xf), ys)
    case (xs: Iterable[T1], yf: (T1 => T2)) => (xs, xs.map(yf))
  }
}
```

Comment: That's because an Iterable is indeed also a PartialFunction :-}

Comment: The issue is really that some Iterables are PartialFunctions, but not all. Iterable itself does not mixin PartialFunction. List does, for example, whereas Set does not.

Comment: Interesting. In Odersky's Scala course, Set was also implemented as a kind of PartialFunction. Why it's not the case in language itself? Perhaps because of performance considerations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600424/why-does-not-set-implement-partialfunction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `List` is both `Iterable[Int]` and `Int => Int`, as you've said, what you're writing is inherently abmiguous. Perhaps I've misread, but I don't see any place at all where you've specified whether you want `FunList.foo(List(1))` to print `"hello"` or `"Goodbye"`.

First, you can use a cast at the call site. I assume you already know this, but just to be explicit for the sake of discussion:

```
FunList.foo(List(1): Int => Int) // "hello"
FunList.foo(List(1): Iterable[Int]) // "Goodbye"
```

If our objective here is to allow the caller to simply write `FunList.foo(List(1))`, you could use the [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/). This means you don't use method overloading at all; instead you write a single method, and the dispatch is done with implicit conversions.

```
sealed trait FooMagnet
case class HelloMagnet(itr: Iterable[Int]) extends FooMagnet
case class GoodbyeMagnet(f: Int => Int) extends FooMagnet

def foo(x: FooMagnet): Unit = x match {
  case HelloMagnet(itr) => println("hello")
  case GoodbyeMagnet(f) => println("Goodbye")
}

def a(): Unit = {
  implicit def listIsHelloMagnet(x: List[Int]): FooMagnet = HelloMagnet(x)
  FunList.foo(List(1)) // "hello"
}

def b(): Unit = {
  implicit def listIsGoodbyeMagnet(x: List[Int]): FooMagnet = GoodbyeMagnet(x)
  FunList.foo(List(1)) // "Goodbye"
}
```

The fun advantage you get here is that the dispatch decision is decoupled from the `foo` implementation, since it's determined by those implicits which you can define wherever you like.

You can also use this to resolve the ambiguity problem! Start with the two implicits from earlier:

```
implicit def iterableIsHelloMagnet(x: Iterable[Int]): FooMagnet = HelloMagnet(x)
implicit def functionIsGoodbyeMagnet(x: Int => Int): FooMagnet = GoodbyeMagnet(x)
```

And then add another implicit specifically for `List[Int]`.

```
implicit def listIsHelloMagnet(x: List[Int]): FooMagnet = HelloMagnet(x)
```

Scala is clever enough to see that this third conversion is more specific than the first two, so it will use that one for `List[Int]` even though they all apply. Thus we can now write:

```
FunList.foo(Set(1)) // "hello"
FunList.foo((_: Int) + 1) // "Goodbye"
FunList.foo(List(1)) // "hello"
```

And you can move the definitions of those implicits into the called library, so all the caller has to do is import them.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the response. I have been trying the magnet pattern and my issue is this - I want the user to be able to write `foo(List(1))` or `foo((x => x*x))` without them having to resolve that `List` should be treated like an `Iterable`. However, I am not sure how to resolve the ambiguity so that the compiler knows to choose `implicit def foo(x: (Int => Int))` over `implicit def foo(x: Iterable[Int])`. I've been trying different things around pattern matching the argument type (defined using magnet pattern of `Any`) but I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: Hey Chris, do you know of a way to resolve the ambiguity for all Iterable types that mix-in PartialFunction? Something like `implicit def iterableIsHelloMagnet(x: Iterable[Int] with PartialFunction[Int, Int])`?

Comment: @Austin - You can define a less-important implicit in a trait, a more-important one in an object that extends that trait (so the object has both, one directly and one through inheritance), and then import the contents of that object.  It will use the explicit one if it can, and fall back to the inherited one if not.

Comment: @RexKerr Thanks for giving me new way to abuse scala. Does that trick extend to arbitrary levels of inheritance, or is it limited to two?

Comment: @ChrisMartin - You can nest arbitrarily, though I don't think the spec makes that 100% clear.