# Scala: Illegal Cyclic Inheritance on method

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, implicit

After taking some pointers on the magnet pattern and implicit resolution order [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261371/scala-multiple-inheritance-differentiate-between-iterable-and-partialfunction-i/27261926?noredirect=1#comment42997592_27261926) I have run into a strange problem pattern matching on my magnet classes. In the first example I get errors about illegal cyclic inheritance, but by switching the pattern matching I do not:

```
sealed trait SeqOrFun[T1, T2]
case class SeqMagnet[T](itr: Iterable[T]) extends SeqOrFun[T, T]
case class FunMagnet[T1, T2](f: (T1 => T2)) extends SeqOrFun[T1, T2]

def unfurl[T1, T2](x: SeqOrFun[T1, T2], y: SeqOrFun[T1, T2]): (Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2]) = {
  (x, y) match {
    case (SeqMagnet(xs: Iterable[T1]), FunMagnet(yf: (T1 => T2))) => (xs, xs.map(yf))
  }
}
```

leads to :

```
<console>:14: error: illegal cyclic inheritance involving unfurl
           case (SeqMagnet(xs: Iterable[T1]), FunMagnet(yf: (T1 => T2))) => (xs, xs.map(yf))
                             ^
<console>:14: error: illegal cyclic inheritance involving unfurl
           case (SeqMagnet(xs: Iterable[T1]), FunMagnet(yf: (T1 => T2))) => (xs, xs.map(yf))
                          ^
<console>:14: error: illegal cyclic inheritance involving unfurl
           case (SeqMagnet(xs: Iterable[T1]), FunMagnet(yf: (T1 => T2))) => (xs, xs.map(yf))
                                              ^
<console>:13: error: illegal cyclic inheritance involving unfurl
         (x, y) match {
```

but the opposite order works:

```
sealed trait SeqOrFun[T1, T2]
case class SeqMagnet[T](itr: Iterable[T]) extends SeqOrFun[T, T]
case class FunMagnet[T1, T2](f: (T1 => T2)) extends SeqOrFun[T1, T2]

def unfurl[T1, T2](x: SeqOrFun[T1, T2], y: SeqOrFun[T1, T2]): (Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2]) = {
  (x, y) match {
    case (FunMagnet(xf: (T2 => T1)), SeqMagnet(ys: Iterable[T2])) => (ys.map(xf), ys)
  }
}
```

which compiles

```
<console>:13: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: (FunMagnet(Function1()), FunMagnet(_))
         (x, y) match {
         ^
unfurl: [T1, T2](x: SeqOrFun[T1,T2], y: SeqOrFun[T1,T2])(Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2])
```

(The only change is

`case (SeqMagnet(xs: Iterable[T1]), FunMagnet(yf: (T1 => T2))) => (xs, xs.map(yf))`

to

`case (FunMagnet(xf: (T2 => T1)), SeqMagnet(ys: Iterable[T2])) => (ys.map(xf), ys)`

Because they are symmetric, I do not understand how one can compile and the other cannot. I am still trying to understand the error, as other users seem to get it from recursive type definitions (which I don't think I'm doing here)

update: I believe the issue goes away if I define the magnets as normal classes and write my own unapply method.